# Enemy Pathfinding through WayPoints with Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, path-finding

So I want my Enemy to move to an Waypoint then increase a List so it can move to the next Waypoint, but somehow my Enemy moves to the first Waypoint and then its stuck at this position.
A awnser would be a dream!
Here's my Code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyPathing : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] List<Transform> waypoints;
[SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 2f;
int waypointIndex = 0;

// Start 
void Start()
{
    transform.position = waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position;
}

// Update 
void Update()
{
    Move();
}

private void Move()
{
    if (waypointIndex <= waypoints.Count - 1)
    {
        var targetPosition = waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position;
        var movementThisFrame = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards
            (transform.position, targetPosition, movementThisFrame);

        if (transform.position == targetPosition)
        {
            waypointIndex++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

}

Btw. in the Console Unity says: Assets\Scripts\EnemyPathing.cs(7,38):warning CS0649: Field 'EnemyPathing.waypoints' is never assigned to and will always have its default value null

Comment: **As the waypoints List I've set 3 Empty Game Objects called: "Waypoint (0), Waypoint (1), Waypoint (2)" each I've placed on a different position**

Comment: please use the correct tags ... [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now ... your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, automatic type conversion, my old nemesis.

Here's some code to think about:

```cs
var v2 = new Vector2(21, 22);
var v3 = new Vector3(31, 32, 33);
v3 = v2;
print(v3.z);
```

The above code does *not* print out `33` like you might expect. It prints out `0`. The reason for this is that the third line is actually two operations: An implicit type conversion from `Vector2` to `Vector3`, and *then* an assignment. When you convert from a smaller vector to a larger one, the extra components get default values of `0`.

So when you go and do this:

```cs
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards
    (transform.position, targetPosition, movementThisFrame);
```

.. you're actually quietly setting `transform.position.z` to `0`. Which would be generally fine, except:

```cs
if (transform.position == targetPosition)
```

.. if `targetPosition.z` isn't `0`, this will never be true, and you'll never move past the first waypoint.

Here is the simplest solution that makes your code do what you want it to:

```cs
if ((Vector2)transform.position == (Vector2)targetPosition)
```

That'll make sure it's only the `x` and `y` that will get compared.

However, be aware that your `transform.position.z` is still getting set to 0, so you might want to do something about that. Here's a very dirty solution:

```cs
var temp = transform.position.z;
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards
    (transform.position, targetPosition, movementThisFrame);
transform.position.z = temp;
```

Comment: Thank u for helping me out. But I got it working on my own I just needed to change               
 if (transform.position == targetPosition) to if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition) < 0.1f) because  the target position has  never reached exactly so the if didnt fire